# QgsPointDisplacementRenderer: setLegendSymbolItem creates dump

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, categorized-renderer

trying to set up a nice layout using the QgsPointDisplacementRenderer, 
but I get a dump everytime I try to load the layer I create through the following renderer.. 
The dump only occurs when I use the `setLegendSymbolItem` line
idea anyone?

```
renderer=QgsPointDisplacementRenderer()
renderer.setCenterSymbol(svgsymbol)
renderer.setLegendSymbolItem("",markersymbol)    # RuleKey as String?!?
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Looks like the problem is the 'rule key', which Python wants as a string, but which is an integer, when I request it:

```
lsi = layer.rendererV2().legendSymbolItemsV2()
for l in lsi:
    print l.ruleKey()
```

so, until now,

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

creates a dump.

The symbols were defined as follows:

```
svgStyle = {}
svgStyle['name'] = r"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Drama_Masks.svg"
svgStyle['size'] = '8'
svgsymbollayer = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2.create(svgStyle)
svgsymbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
svgsymbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, svgsymbollayer)

markerprops = {'name': 'round', 'color': 'white'}
markersymbol=QgsMarkerSymbolV2.createSimple(markerprops)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Jon! How did you define `svgsymbol`? The rest of your code works for me (QGIS 2.18.2 for Win7 64-bit).

Comment: Thanks =) I've added the definition for the svgsymbol above, but that shouldn't be the problem since it's worked like forever.. only since I've added the 
    .setLegendSymbolItem("",markersymbol) it won't do anymore..

Comment: oh I'm using 2.14 on Win7 64-bit .. Documentation says the function was added in QGIS 2.14.. maybe it didn't work right at first?

Comment: In which case, might I suggest installing the newer version of QGIS (v2.18.13) and give it a try? :)

Comment: sadly, it's not my computer and I'm not allowed to install anything.. :P

Comment: so the exact same code works for you?

Comment: [Pretty much :)](https://imgur.com/a/zMEOc)

Comment: The crashing might be linked to the number of points. For me the script worked once, but it crashed QGIS when I ran it again. Then I added more points to the dataset (now 50+ points), and suddenly I could run it numerous times without crashing. Also: I used the active layer. You are trying to set the styling for a layer that is not loaded yet; - maybe - that causes issues as well.